# How to generate difference Image?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am comparing two images. if comparison fails then I want to generate the difference image for that two. Doing in Python. Should be quickest solution.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#absdiff

Comment: what did you try, where does it fail, what errors do you get, what do your images look like (numpy.ndarray? dtype?) Show what you have so far, so that we can actually help, and show that you actually tried something instead of asking directly without putting any effort into it yourself

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps

```
import ImageChops
    def equal(image1, image2):
    return ImageChops.difference(image1, image2)
```

[Link found here](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-comparing-images.htm)

Comment: How do I save the difference image?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Like if the images don't match you want to save the image that didn't match because both wouldn't match

Comment: What I want is if Images wont match then I want to save the difference image between them. So we can see the difference between them...like this Third Images.. http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/comparing-images-and-creating-image-diffs/   In which only HAT is saved. like that.